# Async.map and async.waterfall not working together as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I am using [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async#asyncjs). `async.map()` to bind my data array with a function and  `async.waterfall()` in that function to run function in a series but waterfall is not working as expected. I also tried series but no success.

```
var myData = [1,2,3];
async.map(myData, myExport, function (err, result) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log('Finished: ' + result);
    } else {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
}});

function myExport(item, callback) {
  console.log('item Value: ', item );
  async.waterfall([function(cb){
    console.log(' -> exportData: ', item);

  },function(response,cb){
    console.log(' -> saveData: ', item);
  },
  function(response,cb){
    console.log(' -> updateData: ', item);
  }], function(err,result){
    if(!err) {
      console.log('Perfect: ',result);
    } else {
      console.log('Error: ',err);
    }
  })
}
```

**Output:**

```
item Value:  1
 -> exportData:  1
item Value:  2
 -> exportData:  2
item Value:  3
 -> exportData:  3
```

**Required Output:**

```
item Value:  1
 -> exportData:  1
 -> saveData:    1
 -> updateData:  1
item Value:  2
 -> exportData:  2
 -> saveData:    2
 -> updateData:  2
item Value:  3
 -> exportData:  3
 -> saveData:    3
 -> updateData:  3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `async`, be sure to call your callbacks! In your waterfall methods, make sure to call `cb(null, item)` so the waterfall knows when yo continue. Inside your mapping function `myExport`, be sure to call `callback` when the waterfall has finished.

Working Code:

```
    var async = require('async');

    var myData = [1,2,3];
    async.mapSeries(myData, myExport, function (err, result) {
      if(!err) {
        console.log('Finished: ' + result);
        } else {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    }});

    function myExport(item, callback) {
      console.log('item Value: ', item );
      async.waterfall([function(cb){
        console.log(' -> exportData: ', item);
          cb(null, item);

      },function(response,cb){
        console.log(' -> saveData: ', item);

          cb(null, item);
      },
      function(response,cb){
        console.log(' -> updateData: ', item);

          cb(null, item);
      }], function(err,result){
        if(!err) {
          console.log('Perfect: ',result);
        } else {
          console.log('Error: ',err);
        }
          callback( err, result);
      })
    }
```

Output:

```
    chimmelb:~/Documents/workspace/scratch$ node index.js 
    item Value:  1
     -> exportData:  1
     -> saveData:  1
     -> updateData:  1
    Perfect:  1
    item Value:  2
     -> exportData:  2
     -> saveData:  2
     -> updateData:  2
    Perfect:  2
    item Value:  3
     -> exportData:  3
     -> saveData:  3
     -> updateData:  3
    Perfect:  3
    Finished: 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call the callbacks passed to your `waterfall` functions in order to let it know when you're done, like:

```
function myExport(item, callback) {
  console.log('item Value: ', item );
  async.waterfall([function(cb){
    console.log(' -> exportData: ', item);
    cb(null, item);
  }, function(response,cb){
    console.log(' -> saveData: ', response);
    cb(null, response);
  }, function(response,cb){
    console.log(' -> updateData: ', response);
    cb(null, response);
  }], function(err,result){
    if(!err) {
      console.log('Perfect: ',result);
    } else {
      console.log('Error: ',err);
    }
  })
}
```